# How to always have empty values in the end of a sorting

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I have a list of string values. I use a comparator to sort them by a specific order as follow

```
public static final List<String> CUSTOM_LIST = Arrays.asList("Red", "Green", "Blue");
comparator = new Comparator<String>(){
             @Override
             public int compare(final String o1, final String o2){
                   return Integer.valueOf(CUSTOM_LIST.indexOf(o1))
                   .compareTo(Integer.valueOf(CUSTOM_LIST.indexOf(o2)));
              }
         };
```

So to compare I do

```
Collections.sort(listToSort,comparator);
```

Or for reverse sorting

```
Collections.sort(listToSort,Collections.reverseOrder(comparator));
```

Now my list have empty values and I want to have them always in the end. How do I achieve that ?

Comment: Is an empty value equal to "" or is it null? Or both?

Comment: I have only "". no null

Comment: Use two different comparators, rather than `reverseOrder()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compare interface return a number that marks the difference between both objects. Note that since will always want the empty values to go at the end we must ensure that the integer value returned is bigger (or smaller) than any other that way all empty values will be pulled to a corner of the `Collection`.

```
 comparator = new Comparator<String>(){
                @Override
                public int compare(final String o1, final String o2){
                    if(o1.isEmpty()) return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                    else if (o2.isEmpty()) return Integer.MIN_VALUE;

                    else return Integer.valueOf(ModuleConstants.CUSTOM_LIST.indexOf(o1))
                                        .compareTo(
                           Integer.valueOf(ModuleConstants.CUSTOM_LIST.indexOf(o2)));
                }
            };
```

Comment: A Java Comparator can return 0,1 or -1, so I don't understand the purpose of using Integer.MAX_VALUE and Integer.MIN_VALUE

Comment: Not always. By definition is returns 0 for equal and positive number for greater and negative number for lesser. Many custom implementations do what you say and it would work for your case, but is just for consistency.

Comment: You could optimize this code by returning 
`ModuleConstants.CUSTOM_LIST.indexOf(o1)-ModuleConstants.CUSTOM_LIST.indexOf(o2)` instead of the Integer.compareTo since you would not have big integer values.

Comment: Works for me ...I used:
 `final List<String> listToSort = Arrays.asList("", "Red", "", "", "Green", "","", "Blue");`